# An efficient algorithm to move ostrichs along a line at a constant speed

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

Problem: move an object along a straight line at a constant speed in the Cartesian coordinate system (x,y only). The rate of update is unstable. The movement speed must be close to exact and the object must arrive very close to the destination. The line's source and destination may be anywhere.

Given: the source and destination addresses (x0,x1,y0, y1), and a speed of arbitrary value.

An asside: There is an answer on the SO regarding this, and it's good, however it presumes that total time spend traveling is given.

Here's what I've got:

`x0 = 127;
y0 = 127;
x1 = 257;
y1 = 188;
speed = 127;
ostrich.x=x0 //plus some distance along the line;
ostrich.y=y0 // plus some distance along the line;
//An arbitrarily large value so that each iteration increments the distance a minute amount
SPEED_VAR = 1000; 
xDistPerIteration = (x1 - x0) / SPEED_VAR;
yDistPerIteration = (y1 - y0) / SPEED_VAR;
distanceToTravel = ;//Pythagorean theorum
limitX =  limit1 = 0; //determines when to stop the while loop

//get called 40-60 times per second
void update(){
  //Keep incrementing the ostrich' location
  while (limitX < speed && limitY < speed) {
    limitX += Math.abs(xDistPerIteration);
    limitY += Math.abs(yDistPerIteration);
    ostrich.x += xDistPerIteration;
    ostrich.y += yDistPerIteration;
  }
  distanceTraveled -= Math.sqrt(Math.pow(limitX, 2) + Math.pow(limitY, 2));
  if (distanceTraveled <=0)
    //ostrich arrived safely at the factory
}`

This code gets the job done, however it takes up exclusively 18% of program time in a CPU intensive program. It's garbage, programatically and in terms of performance. Any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: This is either homework, or you work in a zoo that has some _very_ well-trained ostriches :-)

Comment: What do you mean "a straight line of varying slope"?

Comment: @paxdiablo Nah, not HW. My MS program doesn't assign interesting problem. @takteek noted.

Comment: Could you at least link this other answer, so we can see how it can be used/modified?

Comment: I know a much more efficient algori-- wait, did you say ostriches or emus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An asside: There is an answer on the
>   SO regarding this, and it's good,
>   however it presumes that total time
>   spend traveling is given.

basic physics to the rescue

total time spent traveling = distance/speed

btw `Math.hypot(limitX,limitY)` is faster than `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(limitX, 2) + Math.pow(limitY, 2))`

though really it's that while loop you should refactor out

Comment: I have used Math.sqrt(Math.pow)...) hundreds of times. Wow.

Comment: @farm Math.pow(x,2) is also much slower than just (x*x) (depends on underlying implementation though, some check for low integer values in the exp arg and optimize it but don't count on it)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. All good. I can't believe I missed that... I aced Calc 1-3, but distance/speed was just beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to improve is:

There is no need to compute the square root in each call to the update function. You may use the squared `distanceTraveled` instead.

Similarly, `Math.abs(xDistPerIteration)` and `Math.abs(yDistPerIteration)` do not change at each call to update, you may save those values and get rid of the calls to the absolute value function in order to bit a save a bit more computing time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. All true. It's the loop that's the killer, though.

Answer (score 1):

`Update` gets called 40-60 times per second, right? In other words, once per frame. So why is there a `while` loop inside it?

Also, doing `sqrt` once, and `pow` twice, per frame is unnecessary.
Just let `d2` be the distance squared, and stop when `limitX*limitX+limitY*limitY` exceeds it.