# Moving object from one (x,y) to another (x,y) with canvas + JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

What's the best "smooth" way to transition an element (in this case an image) from one point to another in JS? Should I be using trig or is there some magic function I'm missing; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are already a lot of these questions asked that should be able to answer this for you. For instance:

[An efficient algorithm to move ostrichs along a line at a constant speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287397/an-efficient-algorithm-to-move-ostrichs-along-a-line-at-a-constant-speed)

[Moving a Point Along a Line in JavaScript Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985072/moving-a-point-along-a-line-in-javascript-canvas)