# Moving Between Two Points Using Mouse

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I'm trying to move an object on the click of a mouse while the object remains animated. There are a few similar posts on this website, and I've based my code off this answer:

[An efficient algorithm to move ostrichs along a line at a constant speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287397/an-efficient-algorithm-to-move-ostrichs-along-a-line-at-a-constant-speed)

But I want to use a thread to keep the object animated. How should I do this? Here's my code:

```
public void movePlayer(Graphics g, int finalX, int finalY)
{
    int length = finalX - xpos;
    int height = finalY - ypos;

    int oldXpos = xpos;
    int oldYpos = ypos;

    double speed = 20;
    double distanceX = (length)/speed;
    double distanceY = (height)/speed;

    double distance = (Math.hypot(length,height));
    double distanceTraveled = 0;

    //This currently doesn't work:
    move = new Thread(this);
    {
        while (distanceTraveled<distance)
        {
            //move the object by increments
            xpos += distanceX;
            ypos += distanceY;
            distanceTraveled = Math.hypot(xpos-oldXpos, ypos - oldYpos);
            drawPlayer(img, g);
            for(int x = 0; x < 100000; x ++);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to be short on necessary details such as what you mean by " to keep the object animated", and is this Swing? AWT? something else? Please tell us all we need to know to be able to you.

Comment: I'm using a JApplet. And I would like to see the object seamlessly move between the two points. I am going to use an animated sprite, but for now, I just have one picture that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Swing, why not simply use a MouseListener to help you drag the object? If you want to animate separate from the mouse, don't use a `while(true)` loop unless you want to freeze the event thread. Use a Swing Timer instead.  If this isn't Swing, tell us more details (shoot, do this anyway)!

Comment: For the class that this is in, I'm using AWT. But for my applet I'm using a JApplet.

Comment: thanks, I got it to work with a swing timer. I would post my code, but I apparently need to with 7 hours.

Comment: @user1264811: I am very glad that you've got it to work with a Swing Timer. Also, I advise you not to mix AWT with Swing components. Stick with Swing alone.